# iPhone numbers keyboard keeps popping up after using iFrame form (iOS Safari)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, mobile-safari, stripe-payments

Our React web application uses a Stripe element form for checkout (see [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) for details). It injects an iFrame form into the website. As expected, when using the site on iOS Safari, the credit card keyboard pops up when the user focuses on the Stripe input.

But then things go wrong. First, if the user taps elsewhere on the page, the keyboard stays up. Not a huge problem, because you can tap 'done' to dismiss the keyboard.

**But then - ANYTIME a user taps on the site, the keyboard pops up.** Tapping 'done' does nothing - on the next tap, it pops up again. It finally stops after the user focuses on another input field.

I've tried manually calling blur() on the Stripe element when the React component unmounts, but with no luck. Incredibly, you can replicate this issue using the Xcode simulator. What in the h*ck is going on?

Comment: As a temporary fix, after someone submits the card I mount a hidden text input field and call focus() and then blur() on it. Silly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firefox on iOS by any chance?

I just had this issue: I would click on an input box, then click 'x' or 'done' on the keyboard, and then whenever I clicked anywhere else the keyboard would pop back up.

The code that simulated it is here

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input value="hiya">
    </div>
    <div>Click here after clicking the input and the keyboard will come back.</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

It does not happen on Safari or Chrome.